# How to group by in Javascript and add empty object if none exist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want a final Object where the keys are grouped by ids. Inside each key would be an array of objects of the same size. The tricky part is adding an empty object if nothing exists in the original array. Example data

```
const exampleData = [
{id: 1,
name: "Tony",
subjectId: 1,
subjectScore: 25
},
{id: 2,
name: "Lori"
subjectId: 1,
subjectScore: 25
},
{id: 2,
name: "Lori",
subjectId: 2,
subjectScore: 35
},
{id: 2,
name: "Lori",
subjectId: 3,
subjectScore: 45
},
];
```

This is what I tried

```
const reducedArray = filteredArray.reduce((result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item.assessmentId]: [...(result[item.assessmentId] || []), item]
  }), {});
```

Result I want:

```
const finalArray = {
1: [id: 1, Name: Tony, subjectId: 1, subjectName: Math,  score: 25], [id: 1, subjectId: 2, subjectName: Physics, score: 0], [id: 1, subjectId: 3, subjectName: Chemistry, score: 0],
2: [id: 1, Name: Lory, subjectId: 1, subjectName: Math, score: 25], [id: 1,Name: Lory, subjectId: 2, subjectName: Physics, score: 35], [id: 1, Name: Lory, subjectId: 3, subjectName: Chemistry, score: 45]
}
```

Comment: final result is an object and each key have array of array ?

Comment: where do you get `subjectName` from?

Comment: That final result block isn't valid JavaScript- I think you're looking for the `finalArray` to be an *array*, with each element being an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a two pass approach and collect in a first run all `sibjectId`, get unique values and create in a second run the result.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "Tony", subjectId: 1, subjectScore: 25 }, { id: 2, name: "Lori", subjectId: 1, subjectScore: 35 }, { id: 2, name: "Lori", subjectId: 2, subjectScore: 25 }, { id: 2, name: "Lori", subjectId: 3, subjectScore: 25 }],
    subjectIds = Array.from(new Set(data.map(({ subjectId }) => subjectId))),
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.id]) r[o.id] = subjectIds.map(subjectId => ({ ...o, subjectId, subjectScore:0 }))
        r[o.id][subjectIds.indexOf(o.subjectId)] = o;
        return r;
    }, {});

   console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippets (example and expected results) don't completely line up. But with a couple of tweaks to variables and fields, I can get your code to work. See below:

```js
const exampleData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Tony",
    subjectId: 1,
    subjectScore: 25
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Lori",
    subjectId: 1,
    subjectScore: 25
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Lori",
    subjectId: 2,
    subjectScore: 35
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Lori",
    subjectId: 3,
    subjectScore: 45
  },
];

const reducedArray = exampleData.reduce((result, item) => ({
  ...result,
  [item.id]: [...(result[item.id] || []), item]
}), {});

console.log(reducedArray);
```